# How does energy get generated as Protoss in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

I often run out of energy when using Psionic storms and I then proceed to get decimated.
Does it just come back on its own? Can anything hasten the process of how fast energy is accumulated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Energy regenerates on its own for all units. The standard regeneration rate for the vast majority of units is 0.5625 per game second. The only exception to this rate is the point defense drone which regenerates at 1 energy per game second. You cannot hasten the energy regeneration rate.

Comment: Additionally, build your templar as early as possibly so that they have max energy when you go to battle.

Answer (score 1):

Time.  That's it.

If you want more storms more often, make more HT so you have more generators.

Comment: The amulet upgrade was removed.